# vba cycle through labels to change caption?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a list of lables like *lblData1, lblData2*, etc.
I would like to change their caption with a cycle like:

```
For i = 1 To 10
    lblData & i.Caption = "Something"
Next
```

But logically is not working..how can i achieve this?

Comment: `i` is an integer value, this variable does not contain a `Caption` property. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I found out I can do:

```
For i = 1 To X
    Controls("lblData " & i).Caption =  "Something"
Next
```

Comment: What is X?  Please elaborate more. Give some details.